# ServletConfig with out xml configuration in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, servletconfig

How to set ServeltConfig param name and value in index.jsp page with out xml configuration like initParams in Servlet ? is Possible ?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>website</param-name>
        <param-value>www.google.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: You need to set it programatically?

Comment: The other way to provide a parameter is to set it in servlet. But I am not sure if it is exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: you can use `config` implicit object to do so

Answer (score 0):

In JSP, we have implicit objects, in which we have config (This is the ServletConfig object associated with the page) object. But I guess we can't add parameters manually as their is not method for adding init parameter in ServletConfig interface.

If you want to save any parameters you can save in 4 scopes of JSP (page,request,session and application) and use it wherever you needed.

```
<c:set var="user" value="TestUser" scope="session"> //can set any value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ServletContextListener`. When the container starts up, it will call the ServletContextListener class. There you can set your params:

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
     ctx.setAttribute("website", "www.google.com");
  }
}
```